# Yagi antenna without amplifier, would it work?

Tags: signal, antenna

I'm in a big hurry to make a 4g (LTE) Yagi antenna (I have the schematics), but i currently don't have an adapter for it.
Instead i'll use just the end connection of my coaxial cable (Bending the copper cable in a circular form) to lay my cellphone on top.
Example (7:42): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKcz6rEXamc 
Will this even work?, if not, what should i do to get better results?
Thanks.

Comment: What are your expectations of functionality and performance?

Comment: Not so high. From 0% signal to at least 10-15%, would love to get a little more.

Comment: Could you please take your antenna specifications, and list the parameters in here? Thus we should figure a response.

Comment: Sorry, i only have this schematic: https://prnt.sc/oognbt
It was made for 4g LTE in my country, which is used on the 2600 MHz band.
I just want to know if something like this could improve anything whatsoever without an amplifier.

Comment: I hope you realize that at 2600 MHz getting the connectors and/or cable incorrect will **destroy** the added performance even if the antenna behaves in a proper way. I mean: you cannot just use any coax cable or any connector, these have to be suitable for 2.6 GHz. Get this wrong and you'll suffer from signal loss and reflections, then the antenna in the phone on its own will perform better. Being in a hurry, doing things at 2.6 GHz and not having much experience with that means that I think you might be wasting your time.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification.
I do have a "general purpose" coax cable (Simmilar to this: https://files.cablewholesale.com/hires/10x4-bulkbk.jpg) and a solid connection to the driven element. So... Should i try it?

Comment: You need to re-radiate the energy. At least use a 50_ohm resistor at the far end of the coax, so the Yagi is effective. Then place the smartphone very near the 50_ohm to let the Magnetic field  couple via near-field into the smartphone antenna, found by moving the smartphone around near the resistor. May or may not work.

Comment: It won't work. Get over it.

Answer (score 2):

Passive repeaters are quite common, and are most commonly used in the communications industry for line-of-sight issues that can be helped by a repeater who's required locations don't have readily available power or it's not required.  [Passive repeaters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_repeater) can be simply a physical reflection or refraction surface, or can be two antennas connected together with coaxial cable and/or a waveguide.  In an ideal situation, both antennas need to be as high of a gain as possible within size limitations.  Cable and connector impedance and type will need to be taken into consideration, as well as the length of the cable, in order to minimize losses due to impedance mismatches and/or [SWR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave_ratio) issues.

You can make your own antennas, but most factory-made antennas are usually better within spec at your given frequency than anything you can make yourself, and aren't very expensive considering the engineering that went into their design and construction.

You, of course, will need to have antennas and cable that can operate through the frequency range of the cell tower you are trying to connect to, or at least the band you are trying to repeat.

The advantage to a "coupled" type of repeater is that you are able to externally communicate through a highly directional and high-gain antenna that is pointed directly at the cell phone tower's sector antenna, rather than the omni-directional antenna(s) built into your smart phone.  The polarization of the external antenna should also be experimented with in order to get the largest gain.

I actually ordered a kit of this sort in order to gain cellular signal in a truck with a steel cab that I drove.  Since my use was not in a fixed location, my external antenna was an omni-direction type, with much less gain in a specific direction than a yagi or other directional antenna would have.  In my case, my kit came with the cable, and an internal small patch-panel type antenna, and I saw about a 5% non-logarithmic increase in signal.  If you use a highly directional outdoor antenna that is pointed properly, I would expect significantly more than I was able to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

First off where are you located at?
That yagi you posted is for the S-band at 2.6Ghz. Most of the 4G LTE spectrum is not S-band.

Sprint in the US, and some parts of Europe, China and India have limited S-band LTE.

The cell system is not like Blue Tooth or WiFi.  Those are using S-band(WiFi can also use 5Ghz, but you can control that to the degree of turning it off).
It uses 3+ bands.  Look up your phone model and the tech specs will tell you which bands it can do. 900/1200/etc etc.

The only way that antenna would have a chance to work is:
1. Somehow lock your phone to 2.6Ghz.
2. Then get a low loss signal out of it.
Sorry, not going to happen.

If you have to use a S-band antenna I would use dish and put the phone at the focal point.  There are plenty of articles about making S-band dishes for Ham Radio.  They give you the theory behind it, along with the equations that would allow you to customize it.
[Here](https://www.rtl-sdr.com/tag/s-band/) is a page dealing with the S-band for SDR.  It covers theory, plans and more.

I just don't see a way that antenna could be used with a cell phone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is a list of frequencies used by my country: https://prnt.sc/oot0x7 (Movistar). Apparently 2600MHz is not necessary. I could re-design the antenna and set it to work on 700MHz i guess. By the way, I'm not so far away from the nearest tower (I just don't get enough signal as i would like to) so i think it could at least improve something...?

Comment: The biggest problem nailing down the frequency.  Most cell phones(depending on the provider) can use any of the frequencies as required.  I've never seen a cell phone(at least modern ones) where you have control of it.  It is going to choose the freq that it's programed to based on the situation.  And again, how are you interfacing it? It's one thing if you have something like a GSM/LTE shield connected to a micro(you have easy access to the internal antennas), whereas in a normal cell phone, they are all internal and NOT easy to access.   Maybe a new cell phone? Wish I could help more.